# Compactness of Moduli spaces in Lagrangian Floer Cohomology

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology, fukaya-category

I have been reading Denis Aurox lecture notes on Fukaya Categories https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.7056.pdf , and in page $9$ he starts to discuss the compactness properties of the moduli spaces and how we can strip breaking, disk bubbling or sphere bubbling .

From what I understood the idea behind the bubblings is that if we don't have uniform gradient bounds on $u_n$ then we can take a sequence $(s_n,t_n)\in \mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ such that $|\nabla u_n(s_n,t_n)|\rightarrow \infty$ . Now since $[0,1]$ is compact then we can assume that $t_n\rightarrow t$ where if this $t=0$ or $1$ then we have disk bubbling, and if $t\in (0,1)$ then we have a sphere bubbling. (Maybe this is not at all what is hapenning but it was how I interpreted it ).

Now he talks about using suitable rescalings to obtain this bubbles but  I am not quite sure what one does. I have tried to immitate the process that is done in book "Morse Theory and Floer homology" but I am not quite getting anywhere since here we are working with $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$.

Therefore I am wondering if anyone knows of a reference where the argument for this case is made explicitly and I can see what are the rescalings, and the disk and sphere bubble forming depending on the case .

Any enlighment is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen the compactness chapter in McDuff Salamon book ?